# How to set orientation in blackberry phonegap?

Tags: blackberry, cordova, blackberry-webworks

I am developing a BlackBerry Phonegap application and I want to set orientation of application to portrait. For this, I am adding  `<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />` in the config.xml file but it's not working.

I am using Phonegap version 2.4.0.  Can any one help me to set the orientation?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to lock the orientation like this, in your config.xml file

```
<feature id="blackberry.app">
    <param name="orientation" value="portrait" />
</feature>
```

The documentation for config.xml is available here - http://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/param_element.html

Comment: Hi chadtatro this feature only applicable for blackberry 10 OS but i am using blackberry 6 and 7..Do you have any method for this OS?

Comment: @EktaShukla, see my answer below.  WebWorks SDK 2.3 or greater should support OS 6 and 7.

Answer (score 1):

From [BlackBerry Support Forums](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/support-landscape-or-portrait-mode-in-blackberry/m-p/1886551#M28346):

```html
<rim:orientation mode="portrait" />
```

in your config.xml.  [Requires WebWorks SDK 2.3 or later](https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/rim_orientation_element_1594186_11.html).